# Is there a way to get Eclipse's Open Resource dialog to search the middle of filenames automatically?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse's Open Resource dialog lets you search for project files based on a typed query, but the default behavior is to return only those filenames that start with the given query. You have to prepend a `*` wildcard symbol if you want the query to be interpreted as an arbitrary filename substring.

I'd say that 95% of the time, I'd want to prepend the wildcard. The default behavior for analogous dialogs, e.g. those in Visual Assist or Komodo, is to assume the query can be any part of the filename. I'm wondering if there's a way to force Eclipse to work the same way.

Comment: There is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531785 from 2018 which addresses this as a feature request, but it was not implemented yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12+ years later, yes this is officially supported with [Eclipse 4.27 (2023-03 release)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.27/platform.php#open-resource-new-search-behavior), from [PR 12](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/pull/12).

> ### Open Resource dialog now defaults to "substring" search
>
> By default, the search pattern input to the Open Resource dialog is now searched anywhere in the file name.
> That means you no longer need to input a leading asterisk ("`*`") when searching from the middle of a file name.
>
> [image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.27/images/open-resource-auto-substring-search.png]
>
> If you want to enforce the old behavior, where "prefix-matching" search is expected, simply add a leading angle bracket (">") to the search pattern.
>
> [image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.27/images/open-resource-enforce-prefix-search.png]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  The UI you're talking about uses the FileDialog class which isn't really configurable in the way you describe.  To me, that says that there's no preferences view that can alter that behavior.  I certainly don't know of any nor could I find one.