# Eclipse. Fuzzy search in Quick Switch Editor

Tags: eclipse, fuzzy-search

Using **Quick Switch Editor** (ctrl+E) in Eclipse allows one to navigate trough currently open tabs.
Thing that bugs me is: you must use wildcard (*) to performe fuzzy search.
It looks like it's more convenient to use **Open Type** (ctrl+shift+T) functionality that support fuzzy search then **Quick Switch Editor**.

Is there any Eclipse configuration that I miss or plugin that will make my life better?

Kind regards.

Comment: FYI, there is also a similar & older question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036466/is-there-a-way-to-get-eclipses-open-resource-dialog-to-search-the-middle-of-fil.

Answer (score 6):

I use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to automatically type `*` whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, which ends up being essentially the same as Quick Switch Editor using wildcard by default.

AutoHotKey Script:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class SWT_Window0
~^e::Send {*}
```

You could also set up something similar for "Open Resource" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and "Quick Outline" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

Quite some time past since I asked this question, but I think I have something to add now.

[GotoFile](https://github.com/adelarsq/eclipse-gotofile-plugin-kai) plugin, I believe is good solution to above problem. It will perform fuzzy-search on all WorkSpace projects.

As it is it doesn't quite address 'navigate trough currently open tabs' problem, but I decided to improve it a bit. For example, if search term starts with '.' it will prioritize open tabs (search will be performed on all files, but open will appear on top; '.' itself will be ignored). Case sensitive fuzzy-search (with 'In' search term resource `IndexPage.java` will have priority over `index.js`). On startup -- just display list of currently open tabs (like **Ctrl + E** currently does).

Basically idea is to have 'single point of access' for QuickSwitchEditor, OpenType and OpenResource functionality. *true, it will not  replace them, but eliminate 90% of everyday use.*